# whiteoctober/breadcrumbs-bundle incompatible with twig/twig 3.0

Tags: twig, seo, symfony4, breadcrumbs

I've upgraded to new version of twig/twig 3.x.x. As of twig version 3.0 Twig_Extension is deprecated. So I'm getting next with "whiteoctober/breadcrumbs-bundle"

```
!!  In BreadcrumbsExtension.php line 12:
!!                                                                         
!!    Attempted to load class "Twig_Extension" from the global namespace.  
!!    Did you forget a "use" statement?
```

Any suggestion how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately https://github.com/whiteoctober/BreadcrumbsBundle is not maintained anymore for Symfony upper 4.3.
Look at fork https://github.com/mhujer/BreadcrumbsBundle.

Answer (score 2):

We've checked https://github.com/mhujer/BreadcrumbsBundle and it does works.
There is still the same limitation that you cannot use HTML code in the breadcrumb. Only by overwriting the twig file.

Comment: I have made a fork where html support is implemented. We will move logic of breadcrumbs to the twig files, where it supposed to be. github.com/4bis/BreadcrumbsBundle